# retrieve Hex string using MyBatis

Tags: blob, mybatis, vertica, varbinary

I am using Vertica and MyBatis.

1. I am storing a binary information in Vertica as long varbinary column
2. I want to retrieve it as an hex, so I have this code in the mapper

```html
<resultMap id="data" type="some_table_name">
        <result property="long_varibary_column" column="long_varibary_column" />
    </resultMap>

<select id=“getlong_varibary_column” resultMap=“data”>

Select to_hex(long_varibary_column)
From some_table_name
Limit 1
</select>
```

3. In the model I have used

```html
Public class some_table_name{

 String long_varibary_column;

  Public void setLong_varibary_column(String long_varibary_column){this. long_varibary_column= long_varibary_column;}
}
```

I have used String in the model, as the query has `to_hex(long_varibary_column)` even though the column
long_varbinary_column is actually a Long varbinary on the table.

When I fetch the data, I get Null.

I even tried with `byte[] instead of String long_varibary_column`, still, I get Null.

Any clue what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried specifying column alias? i.e. `to_hex(long_varibary_column) as long_varibary_column`

Comment: @ave tied it no luck

Comment: With the column alias, it worked for me. Here is an executable [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-56284627).

Comment: @ave Thanks much! Your solution works. Could you please answer this question, so that, I can accept and upvote your answer.

Comment: Done. Glad to know it worked! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reference the result by the column name, you need to assign alias to it.
i.e.

```sql
select to_hex(long_varibary_column) long_varibary_column
from some_table_name
limit 1
```

Here is a [demo](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues/tree/master/so-56284627).